# What can XML do that JSON cannot?

Tags: xml, json

In [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61346) programmers.stackexchange answer, someone states that XML "covers a lot of edge cases that YAML and JSON doesnt". Is there any truth to this claim, and are there any examples?

Answer (score 3):

[XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformations.

[Code generation](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) from a schema.

Comment: JSON could technically be used to archive these use cases, it's just that there is no standard/momentum to do so.

Comment: XSLT? As advantage? XSLT is an abomination of language. Since the invention of **[XQuery](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery)** there is no reason to use XSLT anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Mixed content is not an edge case. You can't mark up documents in JSON. Did you know that the M in XML stood for markup?

Comment: You can mark up documents in JSON. There's a project out there that does it: http://www.jsonml.org/

Comment: Sure, JSON is slowly accumulating all the complexity needed to tackle the kinds of things XML has done for years. When it finally gets there, someone will invent something nice and simple to replace it, and the cycle will start again.